# Post Single Form Value To Self With On Click Href

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I have a basic form. All the  elements are text fields.

There is a regular submit button at the end that posts the form to another page.

The problem is I have one text field within the form, that I want to be able to post to the form and reload the page after running through a script.

Sample code:

```
<?php 

if (isset("var_needed"){

... Do all this....
}else;

?>

<form id="form" action="post_to_next_page.php" >
<input name="var1" type="text" id="var1"/>
<input name="var2" type="text" id="var2"/>
<input name="var3" type="text" id="var3"/>

<input name="var_needed" type="text" id="var_needed"  />
<a href="#" onclick="...?...."><img src="../image/_apply_code_button.jpg" width="132" height="28" />

<input name="var4" type="text" id="var4"/>
<input name="var5" type="text" id="var5"/>

<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
```

I figure I can do this with some sort of JavaScript that gets executed with the `onclick` handler of an image within the form.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean "post to the form"?  If there is a value in that field, then where do you want the data to go? If I read correctly, the `var_needed` field is already part of the form, right? So the data is already in the form..?  Or what do you mean by "post" data to a form? Sorry, I cannot picture what you want to happen. A little help...?

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="#" onclick="onclick="document.getElementById("form").submit(); return false;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
<?php 

if (isset($_GET['somevar'])){

... Do all this....
}else;

?>

<form id="form" action="post_to_next_page.php" >
<input name="var1" type="text" id="var1"/>
<input name="var2" type="text" id="var2"/>
<input name="var3" type="text" id="var3"/>

<input name="var_needed" type="text" id="var_needed"  />
<a href="?somevar=yes"><img src="../image/_apply_code_button.jpg" width="132" height="28" />

<input name="var4" type="text" id="var4"/>
<input name="var5" type="text" id="var5"/>

<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
```